# Finding number of roots of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $(\tan x)(\sin^2x-a)(\sec x - a) = 0$ and I need to find the number of roots it has over the range $0\leq x \leq 2 \pi$ if:
a) $0 < a < 1$
b) $a > 1$

For the $\tan x$ factor there should be 3 roots at $n \pi$ for $n=0,1,2$
When $a>1$ the factor $(\sin^2x-a)$ should have no roots, and $(\sec x - a)$ should have 4 roots based on their graphs. When $0 < a < 1$ there should be 8 roots, on the $(\sin^2x-a)$ factor and for $(\sec x - a)$ there are no roots.

I am wondering if I am doing this correctly; so if I add all those roots, it should give the total number of roots for the equation. I get 7 roots for $a > 1$ and 11 for $0 < a < 1$.

Comment: Your approach is correct. Whether these are the exact numbers or not- I haven't checked, but this is the way to go about these problems.